# wxWidgets: Delete content of wxGrid cells by selecting and pressing DEL?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxgrid

By default a wxGrid acts like that: If a cell or multiple cells are selected and DEL/Backspace is pressed, the cursor jumps into the (first) cell selected and deletes the first character in that cell.

Is it possible to have an Excel - like behaviour in that when this action is performed, the whole content of the cell(s) is deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just handle `wxEVT_CHAR` for `wxGrid` yourself and clear the cell contents when you get an event for one of those keys.